# Change Executor Memory (and other configs) for Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

How to change executor memory (and other configs) for Apache Spark Shell?

In particular I would like to give flats to spark-shell, like -Dspark-cores-max=12 when I start it so that my jobs in the spark shell will use those configuration settings.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As of spark 1.2.0 you can set `memory` and `cores` by giving following arguments to spark-shell.

```
spark-shell --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 8
```

to see other options you can give following commands to spark shell

```
spark-shell --help
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the spark-shell on spark installed on standalone mode (1 node), use

```
./bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 4g
```

If you are running the spark-shell on spark installed on cluster (2+ nodes), use

```
./bin/spark-shell --executor-memory 4g
```

4g is 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

**DEPRECATED** USE ACCEPTED ANSWER

Write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="$*"
MASTER=spark://ec2-99-99-99-99:7077 /usr/share/spark/bin/spark-shell
```

`/usr/share/spark/bin/spark-shell` should be the path to where the long spark-shell starting script is.  On my cluster there was another script in /usr/local/bin/ but this one was just a few lines similar to above and had `SPARK_JAVA_OPTS` hardcoded.

Anyway, example use:

```
my-spark-starter-script -Dspark-cores-max=12 -Dspark.executor.memory=26000m
```

Answer (score 1):

**For configuring Cores and Memory for executors.**

spark-shell --help

--**master MASTER_URL**         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn,
--**executor-memory MEM**       Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G).
--**total-executor-cores**      NUM  Total cores for all executors.
--**executor-cores NUM**        Number of cores used by each executor. (Default: 1 in YARN and K8S modes, or all available cores on the worker in standalone mode).
--**num-executors NUM**         Number of executors to launch (Default: 2).If dynamic allocation is enabled, the initial number of

**Final commands :**
If your system is having 6 Cores and 6GB RAM.

**CASE 1 : creates 6 executors with each 1 core and 1GB RAM**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077  --executor-cores 1  --executor-memory 1g

**CASE 2 : creates 3 executors with each 1 core and 2GB RAM. The Max memory is 6GB, 3 cores are ideal.**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077  --executor-cores 1  --executor-memory 2g

**CASE 3 : creates 2 executors with each 3 cores and 3GB RAM. Using all RAM and Cores**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077  --executor-cores 3  --executor-memory 3g

**CASE 4 : creates 2 executors with each 3 cores and only 1GB RAM.**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077  --executor-cores 3  --executor-memory 1g

**CASE 5 : if we want to use only one executors with 1 core and 1GB RAM**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --total-executor-cores 1 --executor-cores 1  --executor-memory 1g

**CASE 6 : if we want to use only two executors with each  1 core and 1GB RAM**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --total-executor-cores 2 --executor-cores 1  --executor-memory 1g

**CASE 7 : if we want to use only two executors with each 2 cores and 2GB RAM (total 4 cores and 4GB RAM)**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --total-executor-cores 4 --executor-cores 2  --executor-memory 2g

**CASE 8 : If we apply --total-executor-cores 2, then only one executor will be created.**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --total-executor-cores 4 --executor-cores 2  --executor-memory 2g

**CASE 9 : Total executor cores: 3 is not divisible by cores per executor: 2, the left cores: 1 will not be allocated. one executor with 2 core will create.**

spark-shell --master spark://sparkmaster:7077 --total-executor-cores 3 --executor-cores 2  --executor-memory 2g

**So --total-executor-cores / --executor-cores = Number of executors that will create.**